# Get the first letter of only first and last name in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, character

I want to display a user's initials using only the first letter of their first name and the first letter of their last name. (Test User = TU)

How can I achieve this result even if a user inputs a prefix or a middle name? (Mr. Test Middlename User = TU).

This is the code I have so far (but will display more than 2 letters depending on user input):

```
public function initials() {
    $words = explode(" ", $this->name );
    $initials = null;
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        $initials .= $w[0];
    }
    return strtoupper($initials);
}
```

Comment: how do you know if a name has a prefix?

Comment: I need to add some code to automatically remove a prefix if there is one. Maybe I could create an array of all possible prefixes and then remove them from the username string if it contains any?

Comment: Yes but you are going to have to make a lot of assumption, what about `Kiefer William Frederick Dempsey George Rufus Sutherland` or `Mrs. Carolina Maria de Jesus`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I know it is impossible to predict what every user will input as their name, but I am ok with "Kiefer William Frederick Dempsey George Rufus Sutherland" being converted to "KS". I am also ok with "Bob Sutherland" being converted to "BS". lol

Comment: out of scope of your question, but try to use verbs for your method names, such as `getIntials` ...

Comment: If they are inputting then why not require they input first name in one input and lastname in another with other fields for middle and prefix?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Ok, I will change my code to say that. Thanks

Comment: @AbraCadaver I like to keep things simple on the user's end and make things extremely difficult on my end.

Comment: As a user I find it simpler to have indivual boxes for info that is needed so I don't have to guess if I should enter Mr. Firstname middlename Lastname Jr. etc

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset) and [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to achieve this

> reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element.

> end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

```
public function initials() {

 //The strtoupper() function converts a string to uppercase.
    $name  = strtoupper($this->name); 
    //prefixes that needs to be removed from the name
    $remove = ['.', 'MRS', 'MISS', 'MS', 'MASTER', 'DR', 'MR'];
    $nameWithoutPrefix=str_replace($remove," ",$name);

$words = explode(" ", $nameWithoutPrefix);

//this will give you the first word of the $words array , which is the first name
 $firtsName = reset($words); 

//this will give you the last word of the $words array , which is the last name
 $lastName  = end($words);

 echo substr($firtsName,0,1); // this will echo the first letter of your first name
 echo substr($lastName ,0,1); // this will echo the first letter of your last name

}
```

Comment: To my understanding, this will return "MU" if a user inputs "Mr. Test Middlename User", which is not my desired result. Maybe I need to add some code to automatically remove a prefix?

Comment: @JakeScervino What is your expected result then?

Comment: "How can I achieve this result even if a user inputs a prefix or a middle name? (Mr. Test Middlename User = TU)."

Comment: @JakeScervino okay!!my bad. Updated the answer.Check if it works now

Comment: I would also add `strtoupper`

Comment: @MehrdadDastgirthanks for pointing that out!! I've updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

There are too many variations, but this should capture the first and last names in a string that may or may not have a prefix or suffix that is terminated with a period:

```
public function initials() {
    preg_match('/(?:\w+\. )?(\w+).*?(\w+)(?: \w+\.)?$/', $this->name, $result);
    return strtoupper($result[1][0].$result[2][0]);
}
```

`$result[1]` and `$result[2]` are the first and last capture groups and the `[0]` index of each of those is the first character of the string.

See an [Example](https://3v4l.org/WUfSX)

This does a pretty good job, however names with a space in it will only return the second portion, such as `De Jesus` will only return `Jesus`.  You could add known modifiers for surnames like `de, von, van` etc. but good luck catching them all, especially since it gets even longer `van de, van der, van den`.

To extend it for non-English prefixes and suffixes you would probably want to define them and strip them out as some may not end in a period.

```
$delete = ['array', 'of prefixes', 'and suffixes'];
$name = str_replace($delete, '', $this->name);

//or just beginning ^ and end $
$prefix = ['array', 'of prefixes'];
$suffix = ['array', 'of suffixes'];
$name = preg_replace("/^$prefix|$suffix$/", '', $this->name);
```